# Why is .click not working

Tags: jquery

Why is this not working?

I have used this millions of times before.  What am I missing?

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('span.link').click(function(){
                alert('lasdkfj');
            }); 
        });

        function moo() {
            alert('moo');
        }
    </script>
```

There are multiple

```
    <span class="link">moo</span>
```

SOLVED: I was an idiot and incorrectly entered the src
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js should be http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/y4EV8/ -- Are you sure you don't have interference from something else? Or that you're loading in the link's dynamically?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? In the current situation, it works fine. Have you checked it's loading the jQuery script? Any console errors? Anything?

Comment: works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nPvZg/). Use jquery.on() instead

Comment: @KyleWeller .on is no different to click (in this context), click is perfectly valid.

Comment: @David you're right, in this context .click is perfectly valid and the code works as he posted, like I showed in the fiddle I linked. Just giving him another option

Comment: @KyleWeller Okay sorry - thought you were implying he should use it due to .click not being valid. It would help if he actually posted his question with a bit more context so we can solve it already haha!

Comment: No console errors.  Very strange.  I've used this many times.  I thought I was just not seeing a typo.  Thanks for the help.  I even tried a barebones test and didn't work.  There must be something wrong with the jQuery script load.

Comment: Maybe there is a JS error see your console FireBug

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error happened because of the Jquery plugin is not loaded properly. Try this link

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using `//` is a short tag for the current open protocol. Its the same as he would write `http:`.

Comment: i know its is shorter form. if you are executing the code from local machine (localhost). you will get resource failed error. because the code will seek for the resource in your local machine. if you are using in the hosting server means no need to include the http:// or https://